# How to insert custom html tag using YUI Editor

Tags: javascript, html, yui, wysiwyg, yui-editor

I've got YUI set up and working. I've created a custom button and it shows up fine. What I would like that button to do is wrap selected text with my own custom 'span' tags, just like clicking the 'bold' button wraps selected text with 'strong' / 'bold' tags.

Does anyone have any examples they could point to to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovered the solution for myself, so I'm posting so others may see as well. :)

First, a BIG thanks to MK_Dev for inspiration from his [similar question asked back in April](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/787996/yui-editor-rte-insert-html-element-and-place-cursor-inside). Here is the all the code that's needed for my problem (above):

```
this.toolbar.on('mycustombuttonClick', function() {
        var sSelection = this._getSelection();
        var sNewElt = '<span class="testhere">' + sSelection + '</span>';
        this.execCommand('inserthtml', sNewElt);
        return false;
    }, this, true);
```

Note that this assumes that the button that's inserting the html is on the toolbar.

Comment: This doesn't appear to work correctly in IE8 - where sSelection is an object and not text, resulting in <span class="testhere">[sSelection object]</span>

Trying to find a solution to this.

Comment: BigDave - what version of YUI are you using?