# Wrapping content in custom tags in Javascript and WYSIWYG 

Tags: javascript, html, wysiwyg, html-editor

So just a basic HTML editor for use in a website where I can select any text/elements, click a button and it will wrap the said selection in my custom defined tags. The contents of the editor should also store its value in a text field in the background so it can be submitted to the server.

I need to wrap some content in `<description></description>` tags as the HTML parser on the server side will pull only that content out for presenting in search results. I can't seem to find any editor that will have this function out of the box to speak or allow to create a simple extension to place button and action for it.

Also any editor that can act a word processor is a bonus. I don't have much experience with them, but it's kind of annoying that when you press enter it just replicates whatever the above tag before it was, this leaves me with just putting `</br>` on the first line so all line breaks are single line and not more as the case with paragraphs.

Comment: What did the results of your own research yield?

Comment: http://alexzag.blogspot.com/2009/12/custom-tags-in-tinymce.html

Comment: As stated in the question, not much

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1717094/how-to-insert-custom-html-tag-using-yui-editor

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for that link. Though it's a 2009 article, do you think that tutorial would still work with the latest edition of tinyMCE ?

Comment: Hard to say without actually trying it.

Answer (score 2):

Technically custom tags are not allowed in HTML

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2802715/315168

You might want to use HTML5 data attributes, CSS classes instead and generic `<div>` and `<span>` elements when marking up your text.

For the WYSIWYG: any Javscript WYSIWYG editor will do with your own customizations. Don't, however, expect to have this kind of functionality out of the box as it's a very narrow use case. But making such feature for any editor is just matter of learning the editor APIs how to do it - nothign is preventing you. All WYSIWYG editors are based on HTML `contentEditable` property so they are internally pretty much the same.

Pick TinyMCE if you are familiar with it. If you want to see other options a simple Google search will tell you.

http://www.queness.com/post/212/10-jquery-and-non-jquery-javascript-rich-text-editors